# Glyphicons font awesome doens't work anymore

Tags: php, css, symfony

First , sorry for my english...
. I use symfony2 for my project and everything was great until i use the asset:install command for my css. 
Since this my glyphicons from font awesome don't work.
So this is my css :

```
@font-face {

font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

src: url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');

src: url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),

     url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),

     url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),

     url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');

}
```

And un my layout :

```
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/oahcore/css/moncss.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Any ideas please ?

Comment: have you any error about it in your console ?

Comment: No. I think the glyphicons don't load , my previous path was web/css/... and the new is web/bundle/myBundle/css/... I just don't understand the problem because the relative path between the file is the same

Answer (score 0):

All the font files should be at the location mentioned in the font face.
Use the font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings' for the elements where this font needs to be applied

Comment: They are in the same folder by the way

Comment: but are they being called in the css file where the font is declared. May be the path of the files is incorrect

Comment: I know but what could be the path ? They are in the same folder